# change github account mac command line

Tags: github

I have two github accounts, one for work one for home. I am working on a personal project and can't push to origin master because it says I'm still logged in to my work account.

I reset my global user / user.name / user.email / user.token and it still registers my work account.

This can't be that hard?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [GitHub token](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/) is only used for non-ssh communications.

But if you are pushing to GitHub using https address, and still register as your first account instead of the second one, that should mean you don't refer to the right public/private keys matching your public key on second account.
See, for instance, the blog post "[Quick Tip: How to Work with GitHub and Multiple Accounts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts/)", which manages those public/private keys through a ssh config file:

```
#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-COMPANY
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_COMPANY
```

Comment: Whew, thank you so much for the link, that is very handy. My night can no go on smoothly :)