# how to add deploy key for 2 repo with 1 user on github

Tags: linux, ssh, github, ssh-keys

I create a `deploy` user, generate an ssh_key, I add id_rsa.pub as github deploy key.

this `deploy` user need pull 2 repo, so I add the same ssh_key to another repo as deploy key.

but github tell me, deploy key already in use.

and I don't know how add 2 id_rsa.pub for 1 user.

## update:

I add id_rsa_assets additional, but I still cannot pull.

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa_assets
```

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

.ssh/config

```
Host guardians
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host assets
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_assets
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [github deploy keys: how Do I authorize more than one repository for a single machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656134/github-deploy-keys-how-do-i-authorize-more-than-one-repository-for-a-single-mac)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create two public/private keys with whatever name you want:

```
~/.ssh
  repo1
  repo1.pub
  repo2
  repo2.pub

  config
```

(Ie it doesn't have to be named `id_rsa(.pub)` to work, provided you indicate ssh where to look.
That is where '`config`' comes into play:  the `config` file includes the name of your two connections for GitHub `repo1` and GitHub `repo2` with, for each connection, the path to your private repo key, as described in "[change github account mac command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551540/6309)" and in "[Quick Tip: How to Work with GitHub and Multiple Accounts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts/)":

```
Host githubRepo1
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo1

Host githubRepo2
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/repo2
```

That way you can pull from any of the two repos, as long as you are using their ssh addresses.

Comment: when I run ssh-add ~/.ssh/repo2 it said 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.'

Comment: @guilin桂林: see https://www.cs.indiana.edu/Facilities/FAQ/Security/openssh.html: then your session is not running under the `ssh-agent`. You can get around this by restarting a new shell under the agent by running:

    `exec ssh-agent bash` 

where you can replace `bash` with the shell of your choice. Once you do this, you should be able to run `ssh-add` to load your key for that shell.