# How to discover where 'pip install git+ssh://...' is searching for ssh keys?

Tags: python, bash, git, ssh, pip

### Question:

Does anyone know if there's a simple means of discovering where `pip install git+ssh:///...` is searching for ssh keys?

### Quick background (RESOLVED...see update below):

I am on Windows 10. I needed to install a private remote repository from github using pip in a conda virtual environment. I am the repo owner. I have a public/private ssh key pair set up through github.com. My local key is stored in `C:\Users\MyName\\.ssh\id_rsa`. Using this key I am able to push and pull without issue from github using my IDE, Eclipse.

However, when I executed the following command using my activated conda environment:

```
pip install git+ssh://github.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git
```

I got the following error:

```
Collecting git+ssh://github.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git
Cloning ssh://github.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git to
c:\users\USER_NAME\appdata\local\temp\pip-ghf3ts-build
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,IP_ADDRESS' (RSA) to the list of
known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know that the repo exists, and I know the ssh key works fine; so, I assumed whatever ssh routine pip was calling was not properly configured.

### Update

I have solved this issue since then, and the 'bad configuration' assumption proved to be correct! I added a config file to C:\Users\MyName\.ssh specifying which file to use. Wham-bam, it works great now.

However! I would still be interested in knowing if there were anyway to have confirmed that pip was looking in that directory for ssh keys and configs; so, I'll leave this question open for now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode) environment variable enables overriding the command that Git uses to run ssh. In this case, you want to enable verbose output. On Windows this looks like:

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v
```

Then when you run `pip install git+ssh://github.com/USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git`, ssh outputs debug information, including where it looks for keys:

```
...
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/MyName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
...
```

Answer (score 19):

For deploying in projects with multiple ssh keys do following:

```
$ export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy_key_1"
$ pip install git+ssh://git@<my_hosted_gitlab>/project_with_deploy_key_1
$ export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/deploy_key_2"
$ pip install git+ssh://git@<my_hosted_gitlab>/project_with_deploy_key_2
```

It can be integrated in CI process.

Comment: FYI, GIT_SSH_COMMAND is not available on Centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have opportunity to use **GIT_SSH_COMMAND** environment vars (for example, is not available on Centos 7), you can try "dirty hack" with renaming ssh-keys before copying. This is not good way, but works.

My 'bad code':

```
mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp
mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_git /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.tmp

$VENV/bin/pip install --no-deps --editable "git+${REPO}@master#egg=web_bb_app"
$VENV/bin/pip install -r $VENV/src/web-bb-app/requirements/${BRANCH}_branch_ssh.txt

mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_git
mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.tmp /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa
mv /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.tmp /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score -1):

I have replaced ssh with https and also mention username instead of git before '@' :

Old Version:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/measureprotocol/measure-commons.git@v0.1.1#egg=measurecommons
```

Modified Solution :

```
pip install git+https://abhay-kiwi@github.com/measureprotocol/measure-commons.git@v0.1.1#egg=measurecommons
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (namely "where does pip git look for ssh keys").

Comment: It's also outdated for private repos, now that github disabled https authentication. https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/