# Git clone with custom SSH using GIT_SSH error

Tags: git, ssh, environment-variables, clone, git-clone

I am trying to clone a Git repo using a custom SSH command. I set the SSH command in the GIT_SSH environmental variably be running

`export GIT_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key"`.

But when, after the previous command I run

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:uname/test-git-repo.git`, I get the following weird error

```
error: cannot run /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key
fatal: unable to fork
```

Can you please help me out solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you just run `/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key` in your prompt?

Comment: it show me usage info because I haven't supplied username and host. If I supply, I just get denied (which was expected)

Comment: Git 2.3+ (Q1 2015) will allow a more complete ssh command definition (with the new environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27607760/6309)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You cannot provide options in the `GIT_SSH` environment variable; from the `git` man page:

```
   GIT_SSH
       If this environment variable is set then git fetch and git push will use this command instead of ssh when they need to connect
       to a remote system. The $GIT_SSH command will be given exactly two arguments: the username@host (or just host) from the URL
       and the shell command to execute on that remote system.

       To pass options to the program that you want to list in GIT_SSH you will need to wrap the program and options into a shell
       script, then set GIT_SSH to refer to the shell script.
```

One option is to add a stanza to your `.ssh/config` file with the appropriate configuration:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile /home/me/my_private_key
```

Another option is to point `GIT_SSH` to a shell script that does what you want.  E.g., in `/home/me/bin/bitbucket_ssh`, put:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key "$@"
```

And then point `GIT_SSH` at `/home/me/bin/bitbucket_ssh`.

I prefer using `.ssh/config` when possible, because this avoids the need to create a per-destination script for each remote.

Answer (score 35):

Note that starting with git 2.3+ (Q1 2015), what you initially tried would work, with the new environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`.

See [commit 3994276](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39942766ab9bc738f49f93d4c8ea68ffbaadc305) from [Thomas Quinot (`quinot`)](https://github.com/quinot):

### `git_connect`: set ssh shell command in `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`

> It may be impractical to install a wrapper script for `GIT_SSH` when additional parameters need to be passed.
>   Provide an alternative way of specifying a shell command to be run, including command line arguments, by means of the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable, which behaves like `GIT_SSH` but **is passed to the shell**.
>
> The special circuitry to modify parameters in the case of using PuTTY's plink/tortoiseplink is activated only when using `GIT_SSH`; in the case of using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, it is deliberately left up to the user to make any required parameters adaptation before calling the underlying ssh implementation.

### `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`:

> If either of these environment variables is set then '`git fetch`' and '`git push`' will use the specified command instead of '`ssh`' when they need to connect to a remote system.
>   The command will be given exactly two or four arguments:
>
> - the '`username@host`' (or just '`host`') from the URL and the shell command to execute on that remote system, optionally preceded by '`-p`' (literally) and
> - the '`port`' from the URL when it specifies something other than the default `SSH` port.
>
> `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence over `$GIT_SSH`, and is interpreted by the shell, which allows additional arguments to be included.
>   `$GIT_SSH` on the other hand must be just the path to a program (which can be a wrapper shell script, if additional arguments are needed).

Answer (score 8):

Building on [larsk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221028/110488) and [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607760/110488), you can create a `git_ssh.sh` script such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Workaround: GIT_SSH_COMMAND isn't supported by Git < 2.3
exec ${GIT_SSH_COMMAND:-ssh} "$@"
```

Then invoke your `git` command like this:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key"
export GIT_SSH=path/to/git_ssh.sh
git ...
```

**This is how it works:**

In Git v2.3+ `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` takes precedence  over `$GIT_SSH`, but older versions don't respect `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` at all.

`$GIT_SSH` can hold only a path to the `ssh` command on the system. It can't pass extra command line arguments to that command, so how can we pass extra arguments to `ssh`?

A workaround is to create a script that includes the `ssh` command and its extra arguments. This is exactly what the `git_ssh.sh` is all about: Since we already set `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to be `/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/me/my_private_key`, it is exactly what we need to `exec`, and the `"$@"` is here to pass the arguments passed to `git_ssh.sh` by Git itself to the `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND.`

The `${...:-ssh}` part, while not strictly needed is a nice touch that will make `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` default to the `ssh` command, and thus setting `GIT_SSH=git_ssh.sh` will not break a normal `git` execution.

As added value, this script is totally ignored by Git v2.3+, and the `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is used directly in this case.

Comment: Nice workaround, for those environments with old Git. +1

Answer (score 7):

Use ssh-agent

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/me/my_private_key; git clone git@bitbucket.org:uname/test-git-repo.git'
```

Comment: `ssh_askpass` is also invoked for host key verification.

Answer (score 5):

You can supply any keyfile you wish to use with the Git command like this:

```
$ PKEY=~/.ssh/keyfile.pem git clone git@github.com:me/repo.git
```

or this:

```
$ git.sh -i ~/.ssh/keyfile.pem clone git@github.com:me/repo.git
```

I answered the same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596980

See link for details.

Comment: This answer is confusing and contortedly useless because one should first follow that link and create the script/s contained therein. And *those* also seem contorted, given that (as other have shown) there are ways to do what the OP wanted with simple, git-standard environment variables or SSH config files.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the SSH configuration file for this purpose. You can specify in it all that is required. The manual says "git fetch and git push will use the specified command instead of ssh" but with "git clone" and others works well. Example of a part of the ssh.conf file:

```
Host khnSrv_al
HostName 192.168.1.201
Port 22
User al
LogLevel ERROR
PasswordAuthentication no
StrictHostKeyChecking no
IdentityFile /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/key
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

Example of launch:

```
al@rznCad:~$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/config" git clone khnSrv_al:~/DrktrRepo/GNU_Gdb_10.1
Клонирование в «GNU_Gdb_10.1»…
remote: Перечисление объектов: 275, готово.
remote: Подсчет объектов: 100% (275/275), готово.
remote: Сжатие объектов: 100% (160/160), готово.
remote: Всего 275 (изменений 114), повторно использовано 275 (изменений 114), повторно использовано пакетов 0
Получение объектов: 100% (275/275), 1.51 МиБ | 10.44 МиБ/с, готово.
Определение изменений: 100% (114/114), готово.
```

The line "-F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/config" specifies the path to the ssh client configuration file, the line "khnSrv_al:~/DrktrRepo/GNU_Gdb_10.1" the path to the repository directory for cloning, "khnSrv_al:" the hostname as specified in the configuration file. With this approach, you can use repository access control using SSH certificates and your own CA.

```
al@rznCad:~$ git -C ~/GNU_Gdb_10.1 remote -v
origin  khnSrv_al:~/DrktrRepo/GNU_Gdb_10.1 (fetch)
origin  khnSrv_al:~/DrktrRepo/GNU_Gdb_10.1 (push)

#fetch
al@rznCad:~$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/config" git -C ~/GNU_Gdb_10.1 fetch origin master
Из khnSrv_al:~/DrktrRepo/GNU_Gdb_10.1
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

#push
al@rznCad:~$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -F /ubData/docs/PktDstSSH/config" git -C ~/GNU_Gdb_10.1 push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

"-C ~/GNU_Gdb_10.1" Local repository directory