# Set GIT_SSH Environment Variable in Gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config

Is there a way to set the GIT_SSH environment variable in the gitconfig file?

Comment: What do you want to put into the GIT_SSH variable? Some settings may also be done in ~/.ssh/config instead.

Comment: In my case, I usually use PuTTY for handling Git, as it is quite compatible and has a solid SSH agent.  However, some Git repos I use have interactive login and PuTTY doesn't handle this.  For those, I need to use the SSH client that Git for Windows came with.  I'd rather have `GIT_SSH` set in the config per-repo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [my 2013 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047734/6309) (Git 1.8.3.4), a new configuration has been set: [`core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresshCommand)

> If this variable is set, `git fetch` and `git push` will use the specified command instead of `ssh` when they need to connect to a remote system.
>   The command is in the same form as the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable and is overridden when the environment variable is set.

It has been introduced in [Git 2.10, commit 3c8ede3, June 2016](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c8ede3ff312134e84d1b23a309cd7d2a7c98e9c)

Since then, you have [Git 2.13, commit dd33e077, Feb. 2017](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd33e07766f883c1bbfd20482123e143028f0af6), which has [`ssh.variant`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd33e07766f883c1bbfd20482123e143028f0af6/Documentation/config.txt#L1952-L1961)

> Depending on the value of the environment variables `GIT_SSH` or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, or the config setting `core.sshCommand`, Git auto-detects whether to adjust its command-line parameters for use with plink or tortoiseplink, as opposed to the default (OpenSSH).
>
> The config variable `ssh.variant` can be set to override this auto-detection;
>   valid values are `ssh`, `plink`, `putty` or `tortoiseplink`.
>   Any other value will be treated as normal ssh. This setting can be overridden via the environment variable `GIT_SSH_VARIANT`.

---

> For those, I need to use the SSH client that Git for Windows came with

So for the repos where you need ssh instead of putty, you can use both settings to set *exactly* in your configuration what you want.

```
 cd /path/to/my/repo
 git config ssh.variant ssh
```

Answer (score 7):

`GIT_SSH` isn't mentioned in the [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

"[Git clone with custom SSH using GIT_SSH error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221028/6309)" describes how to pass option to `GIT_SSH`, but illustrates that it isn't part of a git repo config.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there any other way to automate setting the GIT-SSH environment variable as gitconfig would if the option existed?

Comment: @voltair on unix, it would be in your.profile, or your.bashrc. On Windows, it would be registered in your user environment variables.