# Customizing ssh parameters in git

Tags: git, ssh, environment-variables

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) on `GIT_SSH` environmental variable:

> GIT_SSH, if specified, is a program that is invoked instead of ssh
>   when Git tries to connect to an SSH host. It is invoked like $GIT_SSH
>   [username@]host [-p ] . Note that this isn’t the
>   easiest way to customize how ssh is invoked; **it won’t support extra
>   command-line parameters**, so you’d have to write a wrapper script and
>   set GIT_SSH to point to it. It’s probably easier just to use the
>   ~/.ssh/config file for that.

However, when I try to do something like

```
GIT_SSH="ssh -i /path/to/key" git clone <repo_url>
```

it works just fine. Why does the documentation say that no extra command-line parameters are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is not up-to-date, and does not mention the actual environment variable that introduced extra command-line parameters: [`GIT_SSH_COMMAND` (Git 2.10+, Q3 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474220/6309).

It is also configurable with the setting [`core.sshCommand`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand).

Since Git 2.10, `GIT_SSH` and `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` has been made equivalent.
The [setting `ssh.variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576707/6309) replaces what `GIT_SSH` did before.