# How to add ssh key path to a git command terminal

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

The thing is that I do not have root permissions on the remote server and can't use the default ssh key location due to the same problem, even if they are for the user I am currently using the destination is OFF LIMITS.

I have found out I can create an ssh in a custom folder now I can't seem to find a way to pass that to git. To make it clear I can't edit the config file nor can I use any root commands.

There might be something like `git -i ssh/path` but I can't seem to find any documentation on this issue, for all I know this might not be even possible.

If anyone has found a solution to this any guidance is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

[Git clone with custom SSH using GIT_SSH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220929/git-clone-with-custom-ssh-using-git-ssh-error/14221028#14221028)

Comment: Solution? http://www.boxtricks.com/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-with-git/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the environment variable `GIT_SSH` to alter the ssh command that Git uses and specify the path to the private key file:

`GIT_SSH='ssh -i /home/user/id_rsa'`

Comment: ok so i've tried this eventually but it appears that it does not find the files for some reason (i've checked to make sure they are there) 


`"/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/robert/press.lo/wp-content/.repos/.ssh/id_rsa": No such file or directory fatal: unable to fork`

Comment: The identity file (private key) is stored on your local machine, not the remote server.

Comment: i'm using xampp on localhost so, i don;t get it :D

Comment: GIT_SSH does not accept by default options set in but i managed to point it to a script file that does just that :D thank you!

Answer (score 8):

From the Atlassian how-to doc, located here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

1. Open a terminal window and enter the ps -e | grep [s]sh-agent command to see if the agent is running.

   ```
   $ ps -e | grep [s]sh-agent
   9060 ?? 0:00.28 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
   ```
2. If the agent isn't running, start it manually with the following command:

   ```
   $ ssh-agent /bin/bash
   ```
3. Load your new identity into the ssh-agent management program using the ssh-add command.

   ```
   $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
4. Enter passphrase for /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa:

   ```
   $ Identity added: /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/emmpa1/.ssh/id_rsa)
   ```
5. Use the ssh-add command to list the keys that the agent is managing.

   ```
   $ ssh-add -l
   2048 7a:9c:b2:9c:8e:4e:f4:af:de:70:77:b9:52:fd:44:97 /Users/manthony/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
   ```

Hope this helps...