# rsa key in different folder than .ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to clone a git repo on a university server but I have only `r-x` access to the `.ssh` folder. Hence, I can't generate rsa keys in the `.ssh` folder, which I need for accessing the server where the git repo is.
I now generated the keys in a git_keys directory in my home dir.

Is it possible to tell git clone to take the rsa keys from a different directory than `~/.ssh`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726252/how-to-add-ssh-key-path-to-a-git-command-terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking [`man ssh`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201), you can at least specify the path of the private key with -i

```
ssh -i /path/to/private_key
```

The other approach is to use a config file (by default in `~/.ssh/config`), but you can, with the `-F` option, specify a different config file.

You can, however, avoid the config file entirely, with "[How to specify an SSH key with git, without using a config file](http://www.boxtricks.com/how-to-specify-an-ssh-key-with-git/)"

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /path/to/private_key; git pull'
```