# Git on Windows: Force use of OpenSSH

Tags: windows, git

I installed git for windows and when presented with the option to pick Putty or OpenSSH, I opted for OpenSSH. However, I do have putty installed, and it appears that git caught on to this and is trying to use it. (I have GIT_TRACE=2 in the environment variables)

```
E:\blah>git push
trace: built-in: git 'push'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@bitbucket.org' 'git-receive-pack '...
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\putty\my.ppk':
```

Which is really weird cause that ppk doesn't even have a passphrase. Though the real issue is that it shouldn't be using the putty key, it should be using ~/.id_rsa

This was working right after install, but after restarting the computer it started doing this.

Is there a way I tell git to use openssh without having to reinstall it?

Comment: I think this belongs on [Superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I think this is a valid question for StackOverflow. Git and the SSH tools mentioned are definitely `software tools commonly used by programmers`, and this is even `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development` (from [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it appears that git caught on to this

Maybe because `putty.exe` is coming first in your %PATH%.

Check your [`GIT_SSH` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713121/6309).

```
set GIT_SSH
```

If you want to use openssh, you need to [set it to `git/bin/ssh.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221028/6309):

```
set GIT_SSH=C:\path\to\git\bin\ssh.exe
```

That should ensure that the push and pull commands look for ~/id_rsa(.pub) keys instead of asking for a putty `*.ppk` private key store.

Comment: This answer helped me solve the reverse problem: My MINGW install was trying to use `ssh`, but I wanted it to use Putty, so I set `GIT_SSH` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe` and it worked.