# Git authentication in Chef

Tags: git, ssh, chef-infra

When deploying an application with Chef, I've got the code base set to be cloned from a private github repository with the following resource:

```
git '/mnt/application' do
    repository 'git@github.com:organization/repository'

    reference 'master'
    action :sync

    user node.application.user
    group node.application.user
end
```

However, after scanning the documentation for the `git` resource, I can't see how you supply the key file for authentication. I'm also confused as to how to store this key in a data bag, as the file contains a bunch of new lines. Any ideas?

Comment: I have detailed the workflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621251/how-do-i-authenticate-when-i-do-a-git-clone-with-chef/23736540#23736540)

Answer (score 27):

> ```
> ssh_wrapper "ssh -i /some/path/id_rsa"
> ```

In case someone comes across this, the above didn't work for me, I kept getting the error:

```
error: cannot run ssh -i /some/path/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

What specifying ssh_wrapper does is it sets the GIT_SSH environment variable, and it turns out you can't provide parameters in the GIT_SSH environment variable (see [Git clone with custom SSH using GIT_SSH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220929/git-clone-with-custom-ssh-using-git-ssh-error)).

Instead, you would need to write your script to a file first, then set GIT_SSH to it.

So:

```
file "/some/path/git_wrapper.sh" do
  owner "your_user"
  mode "0755"
  content "#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -i /some/path/id_rsa \"$@\""
end
```

And change the git resource part to:

```
git "/opt/mysources/couch" do
  repository "git://git.apache.org/couchdb.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
  ssh_wrapper "/some/path/git_wrapper.sh"
end
```

Comment: This was my experience too. Same problem, same solution.

Comment: Also it's useful to add `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` parameter to ssh to skip host key check.

Comment: This answer is useful for what it does detail, but it lacks an explanation of how to get the private key onto the node.  Of course, that can be done manually, but before that happens this will fail.

Answer (score 12):

We use the similar setup for Mercurial, but it should be the same with Git, I hope.

We use ssh keys to authenticate. The key is stored in encrypted databag (with newlines replaced by "\n"). First of all this private key is created on the node from databag.

```
git_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load( "private_keys", "git_key" )
file "/some/path/id_rsa" do
  content git_key['private']
end
```

And then use it when connecting to git repository using ssh_wrapper:

```
git "/opt/mysources/couch" do
  repository "git://git.apache.org/couchdb.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
  ssh_wrapper "ssh -i /some/path/id_rsa" #the path to our private key file
end
```

Comment: Hey Draco, this is new to me, I am reading the [doc](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/essentials_data_bags.html) but I am struggling a little. It would be great help for a newbie like me if you could detail (spoon feed) how you store the SSH key in an encrypted databag. Hope you find time for this.

Comment: ` knife data bag create private_keys git_key --secret-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa` is this how you do it?

Comment: `content git_key[:private]` didn't work for me, BUT `content git_key['private']` did

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a linux distribution store your ssh key in `<your home directory>/.ssh` and add github.com to `<your home directory>/.ssh/known_hosts`

You can add github.com to known_hosts using the following command

`ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> <your home directory>/.ssh/known_hosts`

After doing this you can clone your repo using `git` resource of chef

Comment: Vineeth - I think they mean for GitHub (and other) private repos that use an SSH key for authentication and won't let you clone without it.

Answer (score 1):

I went through same problem, Only thing I was missing was this command then everything went well:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa"
```

Reference and for my whole steps can be found at my blog: http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/simplest-way-to-write-your-chef-cookbook-that-git-clone-private-repo-using-bitbucket-deploy-key/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548085/268812) by [sadaf2605](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831520/sadaf2605), this was the easiest way for me – I just had to make sure to set the correct user/group as well as turn off StrictHostKeyChecking:

```
git '/path/to/destination' do
  environment 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND' => 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path/to/private_key'
  repository 'git@github.com:your/repo.git'
  reference 'master'
  action :sync
  user 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for myself by specifying ssh key in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host chef.example.com
 HostName chef.example.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/chef.pem
```

The ~/.ssh/chef.pem being the same key I use to ssh into server.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this cookbook https://github.com/poise/application_git. It solves the problem that you mentioned.

With this cookbook, you can use `application_git` resource, specifiyng the private key:

```
application_git '/srv/myapp' do
  repository 'git@github.com:organization/repository'
  deploy_key '/some/path/id_rsa'
end
```