# Cloning git repository from Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have found on the web that we can clone git repository from following chef resource block.

```
git "/path/to/check/out/to" do
  repository "git://github.com/opscode/chef.git"
  reference "master"
  action :sync
end
```

My question is how to use my Git user credentials in this resource block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git authentication in Chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470076/git-authentication-in-chef)

Comment: Mostly not a dup because there is a better answer after 4 years, though SO likes to pretend old questions actually get updated but we all know they mostly don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docu for chef you can add the `ssh_wrapper` parameter for this https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html which will allow you to clone with a certain user.

### Possible `ssh_wrapper`

your `ssh_wrapper` could look like:

```
ssh_wrapper "ssh -i /some/path/id_rsa"
```

#### All Parameters

```
git 'name' do
  additional_remotes         Hash
  checkout_branch            String
  depth                      Integer
  destination                String # defaults to 'name' if not specified
  enable_checkout            TrueClass, FalseClass
  enable_submodules          TrueClass, FalseClass
  environment                Hash
  group                      String, Integer
  notifies                   # see description
  provider                   Chef::Provider::Scm::Git
  reference                  String
  remote                     String
  repository                 String
  revision                   String
  ssh_wrapper                String
  subscribes                 # see description
  timeout                    Integer
  user                       String, Integer
  action                     Symbol # defaults to :sync if not specified
end
```

Comment: I'm agree with you on this.


So there is noway that I can use the user credentials rather than using the SSH? 

I was thinking a way of that I can use secret databag for this. that's why.

Comment: Couldn't find normal credentials in their documentation or in a 10-20 min google + stackoverflow search - so I guess - SSH is the way to go for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an SSH key as the credentials, check out the [poise_git cookbook and resource](https://github.com/poise/poise-git), it handles that for you.