# type yes to stdout request | node.js

Tags: node.js, stdout, stdin

```
var project = {repo: 'a', owner: 'b'};
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

 function getRevision(error, stdout, stderr){
    exec("yes"); // <--- how can I say 'yes' to request from stdout?
    console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
 }

 exec("git ls-remote "+"bitbucket.org:"+project.owner+"/"+project.repo+".git", getRevision);
```

in console I have

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.167)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How I can say "yes" on this request from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to say yes to it, you can avoid the prompt completely: [Git clone with custom SSH using GIT_SSH error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220929/git-clone-with-custom-ssh-using-git-ssh-error)

In short, you need to specify `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` somewhere when git runs ssh.  You can do this in your SSH config file or in more complex ways.

Comment: may be you're right but I solve this by adding "git@" before bitbucket.org :)

Comment: Well, you do know that once you say "yes" to the prompt once, it won't come back on that same machine?

Comment: I don't write "yes" to console directly. It's repaired by itself.
But how can I send commands to console and answer on requests?

Comment: If you really, really want to (and for this application you should not), you can use the program `expect` to interact programmatically with CLI programs.  It's just not warranted in this case, and will waste a lot of time if you try.  :)