# jenkins -github build issue

Tags: github, jenkins

I have been facing issues while trying to build a project in jenkins which fetches the files from github .

Below is the error log i got :
p.s: for security reason i have removed the ssh url of git .I can able to clone from my locally but when im trying it from jenkins it fails . I have generated ssh key in linux server and its able to connect to github .Can anyone please help me on this

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tr-data-events-testing/workspace
 > /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/local/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@github.url---------git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.url-----------s.git
 > /usr/local/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins dxc key 
 > /usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@----url--------------.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@---url-------.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:766)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1022)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1282)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@github.-------events.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing https://--url-----------/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1693)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1441)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:313)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:764)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
 Help us localize this page
```

Comment: there are github connectors now available and you now longer need to go through the conventional SSH method. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure Jenkins is running with the same user account you have created your ssh keys with.
It it does not, it would search for `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in its own `$HOME`.

Second, to debug, you can launch Jenkins with this environment variable set first:

```
 export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

That way, any time it will try a git command involving ssh, you will see exactly where Jenkins/git tries to look for ssh keys, and what is the error.
Make sure you Git is [recent enough to support this (Git 2.3+, Q4 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607760/6309).

But your logs show:

```
The requested URL returned error: 503 while accessing https://
```

So this has nothing to do with ssh. As mentioned, a proxy can interfere.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue by un setting the proxy in .gitconfig file . thank you for your answers

Comment: The proxy should not matter unless your url is an https one, not an ssh one.