# Why my GitHub deploy key is not used on my second private repository?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have two private GitHub repositories and two respective deploy keys on them with write access. For the first repository everything works well but for the second I always obtain:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I check my loaded keys with:

```
ssh-add -E md5 -l
```

I can see that the fingerprints of the two keys are the same that in their respective GitHub Deploy keys page. So why I cannot push to the second repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.

According to [Github deploy keys: How do I authorize more than one repository for a single machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656134/github-deploy-keys-how-do-i-authorize-more-than-one-repository-for-a-single-mac#comment93911763_21130116)

"Git will use the first matched hostname (ie. github.com), therefore only work properly for the first listed Host in the config file."

I found this solution : https://blog.harveydelaney.com/configuring-multiple-deploy-keys-on-github-for-your-vps/

The procedure is to modify the file .ssh/config to

```
Host repository-one
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-one
Host repository-two
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key-two
```

And change in both repositories in the files .git/config the url of the remote

```
git@github.com:HarveyD/repository-one.git
```

by

```
repository-one:HarveyD/repository-one.git
```

And then I could do `git pull` in both repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I see that I'm authentified with the deploy key of the first repository.

To push to the second repository, I have to unload all keys with:

```
ssh-add -D
```

and add back the key of the second repository.

Then I can push to the second repository.