# Gitblit "Authority" ssh key generation failing

Tags: git, ssh-keys, gitblit

I've installed [gitblit](http://gitblit.com) on a local server and can't figure out why I can't run the "Authority" key generator.

It's failing with

> C:\Program Files (x86)\gitblit>authority INFO  Using JCE Unlimited
>   Strength Jurisdiction Policy files ${baseFolder} set to C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\gitblit\data Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.gitblit.authority.GitblitAuthority.load(GitblitAuthority.java:305
>   )
>           at com.gitblit.authority.GitblitAuthority.initialize(GitblitAuthority.ja
>   va:193)
>           at com.gitblit.authority.GitblitAuthority$1.run(GitblitAuthority.java:16
>   3)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
>   ce)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\gitblit>

and this is both with the service running and the service stopped. I'm completely stumped on how to get an SSH key generated and usable on my system.

On a side note, if/when I get this bit working, how do you install it side-by-side with another git ssh key (github) in Windows, to be used with Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which triggers that exception is [this one](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/com/gitblit/authority/GitblitAuthority.java#L300-L306):

```
  config.load();
  // replace user certificate model with actual data
  List<UserCertificateModel> list = UserCertificateConfig.KEY.parse(config).list;   
  for (UserCertificateModel ucm : list) {   
    ucm.user = userService.getUserModel(ucm.user.username);
    map.put(ucm.user.username, ucm);
  }
```

So the config must contain something fishy, which returns a '`null`' `ucm.user`.

Side note: using several kind of ssh keys is done using an ssh config file, as shown in "[How to change git ssh user for a remote push temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551505/6309)".

Comment: Perfect. So I changed the "admin" to my name. "chaseflorell". It didn't like that. The fix took place in the `gitblit/data/certs/authority.conf` file.