# Bitbucket different keys and accounts

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, account

Any way of configuring ssh to use a different key for each account of bitbucket (or github)?

I mean, if I'm going to work with `*.bitbucket:user1` ssh should use key `id_rsa.user1` and for `*.bitbucket:user2` should user `id_rsa.user2`

Have tried it by doing:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user2

Host *.bitbucket.org:user1*
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user1
  User git

Host *.bitbucket.org:user2*
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user2
  User git
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3):

With ssh, you can easily name your ssh remote in order to use one set of key or the other, using `%HOME%/.ssh/config`.
(this works for BitBucket or GitHub)

See as an example "[change github account mac command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551448/change-github-account-mac-command-line/9551540#9551540)"

```
#User 1 on BitBucket
Host bitbucketu1
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user1

#User 2 on BitBucket
Host bitbucketu2
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user2
```

Then, a `git clone bitbucketu1:repo1` would clone a repo from user1.