# Trying to create a new repo but git thinks I'm an organization

Tags: git, github, organization, ownership

(some important background): I am an owner of my work's github repo. for this example I will call it "organization/organization"

So,I created some personal, side-project code and decided, afterwards, to push this to a new repo. I created a new repo at github.com. Then did:

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -am "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:fakename/testapp.git
git push -u origin master
```

Everything works until that last command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I then get this error:

```
ERROR: Permission to fakename/testapp.git denied to organization/organization.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why does git think I'm an organization?!?! Here's my config:

```
user.name=Mad Jon
user.email=personalemail@hotmail.com
core.ignorecase=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=false
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:fakename/testapp.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I'm not doing anything to do with my organization. I don't know why it thinks I'm it. But I'd like it to force it to think I'm the normal user. not the org.

Comment: Did you defined a different ssh key for your new repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ssh url (like `git@github.com:fakename/testapp.git`), the most likely explanation is that you didn't defined a new ssh key, and used the appropriate [`~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551540/6309) in order to declare to Git what ssh key to use.

Your ssh url would become:

```
mysecondrepo:fakename/testapp.git
```

With an ssh config file like:

```
Host mysecondrepo
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_mysecondrepo
```

See "[How to work on personal GitHub repo from office computer whose SSH key is already added to a work related GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12066973/6309)" for more on multiple ssh key management.

---

Of course, switching to https url (as [commented by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085441/trying-to-create-a-new-repo-but-git-thinks-im-an-organization/21085528?noredirect=1#comment31716427_21085528)) works:

```
 https://fakename@github.com/fakename/testapp.git
```

It forces you to identify with your account.
But it doesn't solve the ssh configuration issue.

Comment: That was it kinda. I had altered that file in the past and forgot about it. I wasn't able to get it going using the Host I provided but looked at the remote origin of another project I had. This is what worked:

`git remote add origin https://fakename@github.com/fakename/testapp.git`

Comment: @user2188915 yes, switching to https works, but is hardly the same question.

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't solve the underlying issue. To be truthful, I'd need to look at it in-depth because I am the same user for both protocols and have the same ssh-key for both. This was actually just for a temporary-side-project that I wanted to share with somebody else. I just needed to get it done quickly, not correctly. I know that's not the best thing to hear, but I'm going to delete this repo after a week anywho.