# How to manage one only key per each git repository?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I use git under two scenarios:

- I use some **Github** repositories.
- I'm currently working with OpenShift, which uses **ssh** and **git** for deployment.

First, I used `ssh-keygen` for generating a key which updated at OpenShift site. Such key is stored at `~/.ssh/` and created **`id_rsa`** and **`id_rsa.pub`**.

Then I started cloning a repository from Github, I once did `ssh-keygen` again and started pushing, it worked ok. Then I cloned another repository and started having problems:

I got problems when cloning to the second repository. Every time I try to push will show something like:

> `ERROR: Permission to diegoaguilar/cursoJava.git denied to diegoaguilar/cursoCannibalCreatures.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

But as it can be seen *`diegoaguilar/cursoCannibalCreatures`* isn't correct as it's ***another*** repository.

I even tried removing such repository directory, and cloning it again, same happened.

I already got under `~/.ssh`:

**`config`**:

```
Host cursoJava
Hostname github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_java

Host cursoCannibalCreatures
Hostname github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_cannibal

Host openshift
Hostname openshift.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/openshift
```

And so got:

```
id_cannibal  id_cannibal.pub  id_java  id_java.pub  known_hosts
```

Something like `id_openshift` and `id_openshift.pub` isn't there but as it's not working, I don't care much now.

I created such files and they're `.pub` by `ssh-keygen -f <filename>` and gave different pass phrases to each. I added the content of the `.pub`'s as deploy keys at each Github repository settings.

What am I doing wrong? How is this supposed to work? And, when working at another machine, how to properly obtain these keys, proof it's me and work transparently?

## EDIT

Output of `git remote -v`:

- For cursoJava repository

`origin git@github.com:diegoaguilar/cursoJava.git (fetch)
 origin git@github.com:diegoaguilar/cursoJava.git (push)`

- For cursoCannibalCreatures

`origin git@github.com:diegoaguilar/cursoCannibalCreatures.git (fetch)
 origin git@github.com:diegoaguilar/cursoCannibalCreatures.git (push)`

Comment: Are your public ssh key correctly registered for the right Github repo in your GitHub repo admin page?

Comment: Yes, they are, I double checked. I added all what Ive tried, @VonC

Comment: Can you copy the result of a `git remote -v`, and `git branch -avvv`, as well as the exact git push command you are typing, and its exact output?

Comment: Ok, wait a few mins, please

Comment: Done, @VonC I guess that means it's ok or should be ... Ill try to push now ...

Comment: Nope, not ok. My answer below only work if you change the url for `origin`: `git remote set-url origin github1:diegoaguilar/cursoCannibalCreatures.git` -if you have an entry `github1` in your `~/.ssh/config`, referring to the right key for that repo) If nt, you will keep looking for the default key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa[.pub]`) which won't work for all repos.

Comment: Now I can push to cursoJava but NOT to cursoCannibalCreatures

Comment: "I can push to cursoJava but NOT to cursoCannibalCreatures": That would be because of what I just wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: The idea of that syntax is to help you reference the right key.

Comment: Could you extend your answer a bit, please. Ill thank you deeply

Answer (score 106, accepted):

As mentioned in "[ssh,github,it doesnot work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9551540/6309)", the trick is to not use the default id_rsa(.pub) names for your public:private keys (because yo can only define *one* couple of those), but different names.

But that would be only if you were to access those repos **as different users**

In your case, you are accessing the repos with **the same users**, and **one ssh key** should be enough.

See "[GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-to-user-repo-denied-to-user-other-repo)":

> This error means the key you are pushing with is attached to another repository as a deploy key, and does not have access to the repository you are trying to push to.
>
> To remedy this, remove the deploy key from the repository, and **[attach the key to your user account instead](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github)**.

---

This is for using GitHub for two different users.

You then define a `~/.ssh/config` file in which you reference each private keys by their full path:

```
Host github1
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo1

Host github2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_repo2
```

Instead of using `git@gihub.com:user/repo1`, you would use:

```
github1:user/repo1
```

That uses the key `Host` entry '`github1`' to reference the user (`git`), hostname (`github.com`) and the exact private/public key to use  `~/.ssh/id_repo1(.pub)`

---

So if you have a second repo which use a second key stored as `~/.ssh/id_repo2(.pub)`, you need to use the entry '`github2`' (you can name it as you want) defined above, and then change the url you have for origin:

```
git remote set-url origin github2:user/repo2
```

That way, a `git push` will use the right key (the one for the `repo2`)

If you don't, you will be able to push for one repo (using the default key  `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)`, default name), but you won't be able to push to the second repo, which need a different set of public/private key.

Comment: It worked with out fails at another github folder I got but not on the one I've got problem. When I try `git push` I get same error

Comment: In this case, both repositories are of same user, how would this change the config file and so the `git remote` command?

Comment: @diegoaguilar I didn't realize this is for the same user in both cases. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, btw now I have a problem with SAME repo ... I try to push
and get

`Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

I tried with `ssh-add` but it'll always say passphrase is not correct (IT IS)

Comment: I did this, but when I do `git clone github1:Noitidart/blah.git` I'm getting `ERROR: Repository not found`. Is there any debug logs where I can check whats giong on? Maybe its not using my right key.

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, you can set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`. Then try your `git clone` again. You will have some log to check out.

Comment: @Noitidart You can do the same debug through a config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38474400/6309